# Creating new mysql connection object every time I need something

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm veeery new in `PHP` and I'm trying to do this simple task: get data from `MySql` database.

I made a singleton class to comunicate with database:

```
class Database {
    private static $db = null;
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $connection;

    private function Database(){
        $this->servername = "localhost"; 
        $this->username = "user";
        $this->password = "123456";
    }

    public static function get_database(){
        if(!static::$db){
            static::$db = new Database();
        }
        return static::$db;
    }

    function start_connection(){
        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->servername, 
                                       $this->username, 
                                       $this->password);
    }

    function execute_query($query){
        $this->start_connection();

        [...]

        $this->disconnect();
    }

    function disconnect(){
        $this->connection->close();
    }

    [...]
}
```

This code is working perfectly, but there's one thing that's bothering me. I'd like to know if I really need to create a new connection object, `new mysqli()`, every time I call `start_connection()`. Is there anything like `reconnect`?

Comment: that's entirely up to you. most people just connect to the db once in the constructor and then re-use that connection for everything. but generally speaking, the only time you'd want to connect to a db multiple times if if you need to access the db with different credentials.

Comment: Have you ever heard about "Singleton" pattern? May be you can use something similar in your Database class.

Comment: Why don't you just store the mysqli object in your static $db variable and initialize it once in your get_database() function? That way you can always use this single connection.

Comment: So close connections isn't such necessary?

Comment: Because I'm closing it every time I execute a query.

Comment: @Mindastic - this is pretty much a Singleton pattern using `get_database()` in place of the "standard" `getInstance()` - as the OP states in the question... though I'd argue that a Singleton pattern is not necessarily the right choice for a database handler (Session handler, yes) as you *may* want to connect to different database servers (e.g. www server db and newsletter/mailserver db in the same script to manage newsletter subscriptions from a "my account" type page)

Comment: @CD001 you are absolutely right. I don't know why i missed the 'get_database' when I initially read the question. Please, dismiss my previous comment. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mindastic - you were probably looking for `getInstance()` ;) I know I was!

Comment: Well, I think I got it. I think in my case creating one connection will be the case. Thanks everyone. I'll flag this question as opinion-based.

Comment: I've never actually tried it since I tend to let the db connection kill itself at the end of the script but you *could* (in theory) connect to the database in the `__construct()` function and disconnect from the database in the `__destruct()` function; that way when your object is killed off it should terminate the connection (and release the resource pointer) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a mysqli instance within the Database class and declare it in the "Private Function Database" function (maybe by calling $this->start_connection() if you wish)

If you want you can provide a static function to close the connection as well.